# How to check how much space has been allocated to an account?

Tags: anchor, solana-program

Let's say you have an `AccountInfo` and want to check how much space has been allocated to the account. What is the best way of doing this?

Note, that this doesn't mean checking how many non-zero bytes have already been written to the account. This is about checking the current maximum space capacity of an account.

Comment: are you insinuating that `account_info.{try_,}data_len()` is insufficient in some way?

Comment: Not at all, the question was to elicit that answer since it's not super clear if `data_len` is the non zero bytes or the full space

Comment: ah. damn kids and your high-level languages ;)

Answer (score 1):

According to trent the answer is `account_info.data_len()`. This will give the amount of space that's been allocated to an account.